# Javascript endless loop occurs for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I was working on a search engine for my website when the screen froze. I am assuming that there is an endless loop, but I have not caught the error  on any validation services. Can I get some help?

```
<input id="Query" value="Type search here"></input>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Search"/>
<script>
var titles = ["Pacman", "Tu95", "Tank Trouble", "HTML", "Test", "Print", "Search"];
var links = ["http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/2015/03/pacman.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/p/tu95_23.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/p/tu95.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/2015/03/html-i-used-html-for-this-console.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/2015/03/test-post.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/2015/03/print-page.html", "http://www.mikeyrichards.co.vu/2015/03/search.html"];
var titleswork = [];
var titlesworknumbers = [];
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    titleswork = [];
    titlesworknumbers = [];
    if (document.getElementById("results")) {
        var clear = document.getElementById("results");
        clear.parentNode.removeChild(clear);
    }
    var letterthroughdata = 0;
    var data = document.getElementById("Query").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        if (titles[i].length < data.length) {} else {
            while (letterthroughdata < data.length) {
                if (titles[i] === data[letterthroughdata]) {
                    letterthroughdata++;
                }
            }
            if (letterthroughdata === data.length) {
                titleswork.push(titles[i]);
                titlesworknumbers.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(titleswork);
console.log(titlesworknumbers);
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.setAttribute("id", "results");
for (var i = 0; i < titleswork.length; i++) {
    var y = document.createTextNode(titleswork[i] + ": " + links[titlesworknumbers[i]]);
    x.appendChild(y);
    var brake = document.createElement("br");
    x.appendChild(brake);
    var z = document.getElementById("post-body-2820145598585075365");
}
z.appendChild(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone ident that code please?

Comment: Your while loop will loop indefinitely if the if statement is ever false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an infinite loop:

```
while (letterthroughdata < data.length) {
    if (titles[i] === data[letterthroughdata]) {
        letterthroughdata++;
    }
}
```

If at any point you have a situation where `letterthroughdata` is less than `data.length` and `titles[i]` is not equal to `data[letterthroughdata]`, this will loop forever.